# Как отключить выбор времени в Bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datepicker

Код библиотеки [здесь](http://pastebin.com/6T9tfziR) требует также [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Как отключить выбор временного интервала при клике на поле выбора даты? Понимаю, что библиотека старая, но обновлять сейчас времени нет.

сейчас по шагам получается так, как на скринах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему не использоть просто Date Picker? https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ например?

Comment: потому что таймпикер требуется в другой ситуации в рамках этого же проекта.

Answer (score 0):

[Документация](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format)

> Смотрите [momentjs'](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) мануал для правильных форматов. Формат также диктует, какие компоненты будут отражены, например MM/dd/YYYY не будет отображать выбор времени.

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});
```

Comment: для новой библиотеки это работает, но не для моего случая

Comment: @ultrabatya какой версии Ваша библиотека?

Comment: @ultrabatya выложите пример(код) инициализации `datetimepicker` по Вашей библиотеке(включая все подключаемые файлы) в текст вопроса или на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), чтобы можно было увидеть версии файлов и саму проблему наяву.

Comment: @ultrabatya попробуйте в нашем ответе вместо `format` использовать `formatDate` или `dateFormat`. Также вариант использовать `data-format="dd/MM/yyyy"` в теге `Input` для календаря.